# python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, macos-monterey

When I am running `docker-compose up` it gives me error:

> python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I am using MacOS Monterey,
Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
Docker Compose version v2.15.1

Here is my docker compose file

```
beanstalk-django:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate api && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      gpsdataviz-db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - "gpsdataviz-db"
    environment:
      - USER=${USER}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /code
```

I have tried changing permissions of docker and terminal from settings but not working either

Comment: The `volumes:` block overwrites everything in `/code` (probably your entire application) and replaces it with content from your host system.  Does deleting that block help?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue but I fixed it as follows.

1. Open "System Preference" in the Apple menu
2. Open the "Privacy" tab
3. Click "Full Disk Access"
4. Click "+"
5. Add "Docker" and "Terminal", and check them
6. Restart Docker and Terminal

[image]